How can I find details of all version of a package in nix?
I’m using Nix Flakes, and I want to learn how to find all versions of a package (e.g., jq) with the following output:
From the channel github:NixOS/nixpkgs:
    •   Version 1.0.0 was included in git revision x1
    •   Version 1.0.1 was included in git revision x2
    •   And so on…

Currently, I am only able to find the latest version using NixOS Package Search.

That's a lot less detail than "all details". For all details, nix-diff is your friend.

It seems like there is no official way to do that (see on the NixOS Discourse: Why is there only one version in nixpkgs?).
Some options that are available for that purpose are:

https://lazamar.co.uk/nix-versions/ (can filter by channel)
https://history.nix-packages.com (seems to be the spiritual successor of lazamar, but can't be filtered by channel)
https://www.nixhub.io/ (is more focused on devbox and also can't be filtered by channel)

